# Select xml node by attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I need to read an xml node in javascript, just if a certain attr has a specific value. Is there any way without using a loop? I mean something like:

```
x = xml.getElementsByTagName("someXmlTag")[someAttr=someValue];
```

Comment: does your `environment` support xpath? (i.e, is there an `evaluate` method on `xml` ... if this is in firefox at least and `xml` is an xml document, it seems you could use `xml.querySelector('someXmlTag[someAttr=someValue]');`

Comment: I think so. I'm trying something like var matches = xml.querySelectorAll('Tracking[event=viewable_impression]') but still no results. This returns a nodelist object, and I need the value.

Comment: iterate through the nodelist ... if you only want the FIRST match (or there is only one) see the answer vvvv below - i.e. use `querySelector` not `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in firefox

```
var x = xml.querySelector('someXmlTag[someAttr=someValue]');
```

YMMV with other browsers